# Getting random items up to a certain price

Tags: typescript, algorithm, random

I have a map of 73 items, each item has a price and I need to make a random list of 6 items, the sum of items must not be greater than N. I don't know what algorithm to use to implement this.

Can you tell me what algorithm can be done for this?

P.S. I'm want to write this functionality in Typescript

I can only think of an idiotic way, to randomize items until there is a list with the right sum or cheaper.

Comment: There's a lot of corner cases, but "randomize items until there is a list with the right sum or cheaper" is the way. You just optimize it with "filter items that couldn't fit anyways" and some more

Comment: Your "idiotic" way is basic rejection sampling and it seems fine to me. The problem with keeping any existing choices is that it is bound to introduce bias. By the way, it is not clear if the items need to be *separate* items.

Comment: Assuming that you want 6 separate items, there are 73 choose 6 possible combinations, which is 170 million.  That's not a big number for a computer. So in theory, you could generate every possible combination, and count how many have a sum not greater than N. If the resulting count is C, then generate a uniformly distributed random number between 1 and C inclusive, and choose the corresponding combination. That way, every valid combination has an equal chance of being chosen.

Comment: I have website [Dota 2 Randomizer](https://dota-2-randomizer.vercel.app), the items on it are items from Dota 2. I need that the sum of all "Primary Items" does not exceed for example 20.000 gold. And according to the idea the amount of gold that can not be exceeded, will be specified by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick a random solution to a backpack problem, so use dynamic programming. The main idea is as follows:

1. Consider item `i` and the decision whether to add it to your partial solution.
2. Say the number of solutions containing `i` is `A` and *not* containing `i` is `B`
3. Choose `i` with probability `p=A/(A+B)`

This way you choose each final solution with equal probability.

The numbers in 2. can be taken from the standard dynamic programming table for this problem. This is a table `T` with dimensions `73x6xN` with `T[i,j,n]` contains the number of sets of items that:

- have `j` elements (`j<=6`)
- chosen from items `0..i`
- with price <= `n`

Filling this table is a standard dynamic programming routine.